# Remove ontology annotation using OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am trying to remove some literal Annotations from an ontology using OWLAPI version 4.0.2 (from Maven)

In this purpose I am using the RemoveOntologyAnnotation class and the manager applyChange() method.
Here is the (simplified) code I use:

```
    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology ontology = null;
    File ontologyFile = new File(ontologyFileName);
    try {
        ontology = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(ontologyFile);
    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (OWLClass cls : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
        for (OWLAnnotation annotation : EntitySearcher.getAnnotations(cls.getIRI(), ontology)) {
            if (annotation.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
                RemoveOntologyAnnotation rm = new RemoveOntologyAnnotation(ontology, annotation);
                System.out.println(m.applyChange(rm));
            }
        }
    }
```

The applyChange() method is always returning "UNSUCCESSFULLY"
And I could not find any documentation about why the annotation removing don't work.

N.B.: found some indications here http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/mailman/message/28203984/
Where it seems to work

Comment: Ontology annotations are annotations that are attached to the ontology IRI itself; what you are after are annotations assertions. @dhke has already provided a good answer on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also noted in the mailing list thread linked in your question, annotations on ontologies and annotations on ontology elements are two different things.

`RemoveOntologyAnnotation` only removes annotations on the ontology itself.

Annotations on elements are represented using axioms, specifically [`OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom`](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_0_1/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom.html)s: Consequently, they have to be removed using [`OWLOntologyManager.removeAxiom()`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyManager.html#removeAxiom%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology,%20org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom%29) or similar means:

```
for (OWLClass cls : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
    for (OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom annAx : EntitySearcher.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(cls.getIRI(), ontology)) {
        if (annAx.getValue().getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
            m.removeAxiom(annAx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use new RemoveAxiom(annAx) for each change, then collect the changes and apply them all at once, in the same way @Djast has done in the original question

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had tried to remove the Annotation Axiom before but only managed to remove the classe axiom...